# How to use subdomain routing when a base path is present (and with base path appended only to specific routes)?

Tags: next.js, vercel, base-path, nextjs-rewrites

I have a nextjs (v13) app with basePath

- `basePath: /basePath` in `nextjs.config`
- NOT using a custom subdomain in production: https://DEPLOYED_URL/basePath/...
- pages/

  - index.tsx # route: DEPLOYED_URL/basePath

    - subpath/index.tsx # route: DEPLOYED_URL/basePath/subpath

That works as expected but I want to **add a new route matching a custom subdomain on Vercel WITHOUT showing the base path**:

- subdomain: https://subdomain.DEPLOYED_URL) - This is configured via a CNAME and it's valid in "vercel domains"
- page: /new-page
- On localhost I can easily open the page (without a subdomain) at http://localhost:3000/basePath/new-page, by prepending the base path in the url
- When deployed, browser should display: `https://subdomain.DEPLOYED_URL/new-page` **WITHOUT the base path**

I have tried different approaches to get this to work on Vercel but neither will yield to the expected behaviour (either it's 404 on vercel or next side, or requires the base path in the url for the new page)

**nextjs.config.js rewrites**

```
rewrites() {
    return {
        beforeFiles: [
            {
                # I have also tried with a catch-all pattern: "source": "/(.*)",
                "source": '/new-page'
                has: [
                    {
                        type: 'host',
                        value: 'subdomain.DEPLOYED_URL',
                    },
                ],
                destination: '/basePath/new-page'
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

**vercel.json rewrites**

```
{
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/new-page",
        "has": [
          {
            "type": "host",
            "value": "subdomain.DEPLOYED_URL"
          }
        ],
        "destination": "/basePath/new-page"
      }
    ]
}
```

**middleware rewrites**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export const getSubdomain = (host?: string | null) => {
    let subdomain: string | null = null
    if (!host && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        host = window.location.host
    }

    if (host?.includes('.')) {
        const candidate = host.split('.')[0]
        if (candidate) subdomain = candidate
    }
    
    return subdomain
}

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone()

    if (/\.(.*)$/.test(url.pathname) || url.pathname.includes('_next')) return

    const host = req.headers.get('host')
    const subdomain = getSubdomain(host)
    if (subdomain) {
        url.pathname = `/${subdomain}${url.pathname}`
    }

    return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
}
```

I am aware I can use a custom server for this, but I'd rather avoid that to keep the app clean and scalable.